# Cordova keeps replacing my code with default Hello World app

Tags: android, cordova, gradle

I just learned about the presence of Apache Cordova today and trying to create my own app to figure out stuff. All of the steps I followed on the Cordova documentations page work fine until I finally run my app with `cordova run android` and my code (which I already changed in "index.html" and other related stuff) keeps being replaced to the default "Hello World" app. What did I do wrong here?

Comment: Can you please post some code ?

Comment: Let just say I modified the default Apache index.html and added a `<button>Test</button>` in the div.app dom. When I ran the app it replaced my code and deleted my changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only modify the html in .\www - this gets copied to platforms\android\src\app\main\assets\www as part of the build process

Comment: I modified it in the platforms\android\src\app\main\assets\www folder

Comment: that's the problem then. You need to modify it in .\www - that then gets copied to the platforms folder during the build process